# How to build regex for following, i have done half?

Tags: regex

**`http://con.google.com/video/daTUTOEl-OMBccnY9.mp4`**

I need to check for URL which has all this attribute

```
/https?:\/\/con\.google\.com\/video\//
```

With above Regex I can get to video/ but after that I need to check if its seperated by a `-` or not daTUTOEl => 9characters both number and string
OMBccnY9 => 9characters both number and string.

Comment: Something like `http:\/\/con\.google\.com\/video\/\w{,8}-\w{,8}.mp4`?  Try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/HqnG3Z/1)

Comment: Your is correct but I want in JS

Comment: http:\/\/con\.google\.com\/video\/\w{8}-\w{8}.\w{3}

Answer (score 0):

Those are 8 characters not 9,

Try following regex

```
https?:\/\/con\.google\.com\/video\/(?:\w+){8}-(?:\w+){8}.mp4
```

See it working here

https://regex101.com/r/IvNKc1/1